# cant download file from remote server, 'no such file'

Tags: wget

so iv been trying my damnedest to download a .txt file from a (windows based) game server, to my (linux) based web server, iv tryied different variables with php (ie fopen, ftp_get()) with no success (errors such as stream denied etc), so i ended up trying wget through my linux terminal on cpanel, as far as i can tell it can read the file size im pointing at but returns 'no such file' etc and i have tried verious combos on trying this, but my most basic is this,

```
wget -d --no-passive-ftp 

ftp://jizzm:'(RyLEc09lI3)l5'@194.147.122.188:8821/194.147.122.188_2302/WhiteList.txt
```

here is the debug read out,

```
**bash-4.1$ wget -d --no-passive-ftp ftp://jizzm:'******'@194.147.122.188:8821/194.147.122.188_2302/WhiteList.txt Setting --passive-ftp (passiveftp) to 0 DEBUG output created by Wget
1.12 on linux-gnu.
--2019-04-19 06:30:14--  ftp://jizzm:*password*@194.147.122.188:8821/194.147.122.188_2302/WhiteList.txt
           => `WhiteList.txt' Connecting to 194.147.122.188:8821... connected. Created socket 3. Releasing 0x0000000000de8d90 (new refcount 0). Deleting unused 0x0000000000de8d90. Logging in as jizzm ... 220 TCAdmin FTP Server
--> USER jizzm 331 User name okay, need password.
--> PASS ****** 230 User logged in, proceed. Logged in!
==> SYST ...
--> SYST 215 Windows_NT done.    ==> PWD ...
--> PWD 257 "/" is current directory done.
==> TYPE I ...
--> TYPE I 200 Command okay. done.  changing working directory Prepended initial PWD to relative path:    pwd: '/'    old: '194.147.122.188_2302'   new: '/194.147.122.188_2302'
==> CWD (1) /194.147.122.188_2302 ...
--> CWD /194.147.122.188_2302 250 CWD command successful. done.
==> SIZE WhiteList.txt ...
--> SIZE WhiteList.txt 213 20 20 conaddr is: 194.147.122.188
==> PORT ... conaddr is: 198.54.114.5 Local socket fd 4 bound. binding to address 198.54.114.5 using port 44880.
--> PORT 198,54,114,5,175,80 200 Port ok. done.    ==> RETR WhiteList.txt ...
--> RETR WhiteList.txt 550 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 198.54.114.5:44880 No such file `WhiteList.txt'. Closed fd 4 Closed fd 3
```

*some basic info,
-read somewhere that selinux could be a problem, talked to my provider and they are not for helping me with that.
-file permissions iv double check and tried diff combos of file permissions on the remote.
-read somewhere there could be encodeing issues between windows/linux? (i have limited knowledge so have no understanding of this)
anyone able to help out? thanks!*

Comment: Are you sure you have permissions to read the file _on the Windows server?_

Comment: iv talked to server admin and he says permissions are set, he even changed them to '777' for testing, iv tried setting them from filezilla myself, it tells me they are set but when i check them it doesnt show me what permissions are set? (ie squares im guessing 'default' rather than showing me 'x' or ticks...

Comment: That's not what Windows permissions look like at all; the '777' is probably just something made up by their FTP server. The admin should check with `icacls` or something like that... or in fact, with `procmon` to see what happens when the FTP server tries accessing that file.

Comment: this is what im taking about via filezilla? https://d2hzlohlg26lpl.cloudfront.net/uploads/default/original/3X/1/7/17736ef36fc663689f26064fda2a7c1026d15917.gif

Comment: iv just realised now what you mean haha, yah that would be the reason its not showing me the actual permissions on filezilla, according to server admin permissions are 'set'?....he says he can winscp download from his side

Comment: passive vs. active ftp?

Comment: The log file wluld indicaye that file permissions are not the problem - its likely to be an issue with (iptables/firewall) connection tracking or possibly selinux preventing you from talking on the port. FTP is a horrible protocol using multiple ports - the control port is open but thr data port is broken.

Comment: id to use --no-passive-ftp, as it connect on port:5000 and i may be talking jibberish here, but im guessing it needs to connect on port:8821....am i wrong in thinking you can force it to use a certain port for both (ie the return port is not open on the local server?)

Comment: @davidgo would that mean, simply getting my server admins to open the return ports may work or is there more to it?, also what other options would i have to retrieve the file?

Comment: got it sorted, just had to open the return port on server...